# Bottom align item in sidebar

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Using vuetify I am unable to determine the correct way of using flex to position a list at the bottom of a side nagiation drawer. I have tried a number of combinations the newest of which is as follows:

```
<template>
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-navigation-drawer
        v-model="drawer"
        app
        color="grey lighten-3"
        mini-variant
        permanent
        expand-on-hover
        class="d-flex fill-height"
    >
      <v-row class="fill-height">
          <v-col class="align-self-start justify-start">
            <v-avatar></v-avatar>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item-group>
                <v-list-item>
                  <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon>mdi-map-search-outline</v-icon>
                  </v-list-item-icon>
                  <v-list-item-content>Search</v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
                <v-list-item>
                  <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon>mdi-compare</v-icon>
                  </v-list-item-icon>
                  <v-list-item-content>Compare</v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
                <v-list-item>
                  <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon>mdi-trophy</v-icon>
                  </v-list-item-icon>
                  <v-list-item-content>Ranked</v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list-item-group>
            </v-list>
          </v-col>
          <v-col dense class="align-self-end justify-end">
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item-group>
                <v-list-item>
                  <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon>mdi-account</v-icon>
                  </v-list-item-icon>
                  <v-list-item-content>Account</v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list-item-group>
            </v-list>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-main>
      <!--  -->
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      drawer: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The problem with this approach is that the items move around when the drawer is opening and closing. What would be the simplest layout of columns and rows to get the second list aligned to the bottom without side effects?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you've written is already working appropriately, is this the intended behavior below?

Update: The bottom list item was re-rendering on close.

Added item to original v-list and added fixed positioning class, now at bottom and no re-render.

```css
.fixedBottom {
  position: fixed !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <template>
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-navigation-drawer
        v-model="drawer"
        app
        color="grey lighten-3"
        mini-variant
        permanent
        expand-on-hover
        class="d-flex fill-height"
    >
      <v-row class="fill-height">
          <v-col>
            <v-avatar></v-avatar>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item-group>
                <v-list-item>
                  <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon>mdi-map-search-outline</v-icon>
                  </v-list-item-icon>
                  <v-list-item-content>Search</v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
                <v-list-item>
                  <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon>mdi-compare</v-icon>
                  </v-list-item-icon>
                  <v-list-item-content>Compare</v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
                <v-list-item>
                  <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon>mdi-trophy</v-icon>
                  </v-list-item-icon>
                  <v-list-item-content>Ranked</v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list-item-group>
              <v-list-item-group class="fixedBottom">
                <v-list-item>
                  <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon>mdi-account</v-icon>
                  </v-list-item-icon>
                  <v-list-item-content>Account</v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list-item-group>
            </v-list>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-main>
      <!--  -->
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data () {
    return {
      drawer: true
    }
  }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you look when the draw opens and closes the bottom item moves, that is not intended.

Comment: I see now, the bottom list and icon is re-rendering on close.

Comment: Updated previous reply, added fixed bottom position to your desired item and added it to main v-list

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the need to use custom css and only vuetify components?